# Can't authorize GoogleCL via command line

Tags: javascript, python, googlecl

I need to upload some big videos from my remote VPS to youtube using GoogleCL. To authorize the access you need to click on the submit button via the gdata python browser to get the token from Google, this button is based on javascript so it appears dislabed and I can't go forward in the process.
I searched the googlecl wiki but there's no info about this.
How I do I get the access from the command line?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never used GoogleCL nor did I *exactly* understand the issue, but in case you can achieve your goal from the console using your keyboard, i.e. using certain button presses, you can always re-create this scenario by providing the same sequence of control keys to the GoogleCL process via `stdin`. In that case you would write quite a small wrapping program using Python's `subprocess` module and then send the right sequence of key strokes via stdin.

Comment: How can you reproduce a javascript button press? That seems to be the problem.